# howto background a locationmanager with nstimer?

Tags: ios, background, gps, cllocationmanager, locationmanager

I have a problem with ios sdk.
I need to set a timer that I update the phone's location every xx minutes in the background.
When the position has an accuracy of 10 meters should be saved to a local db with a method that I have ready.
How can I do? How can I preserve the battery? Does anyone have some sample code to do this?

The timer can be started and stopped with a button in a view.

Thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, NSTimer is paused when your app is in background state. You need to use startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges or startUpdatingLocation to get user's location in background state.

Comment: I found an application that works exactly as I want. His name is "My locus". In other words, run a timer in the foreground which continues to work in the background and every10 minutes starting the locationmanager, save the position and stops the locationmanager.

Every 10 minutes (app in background), the gps arrow indicator appear and disappear.. very good!

This is the best way to save battery life! how do I make it? please help me!

thank youu